# How did my git logs/refs/heads/master file become 2GB large? How to reduce?

Tags: git

I have a git repo which is 24M in size. When I push this into a folder I created with git init --bare the logs/refs/heads/master file becomes 2 GB large. When I clone it to another location the size is back to 24M.

Why does the master file become so large?

I've done this many times before without this happening - but for this occasion I was pushing from a windows remote desktop to a shared folder on my Mac. Could this be part of the reason that this is happening?

Comment: More information please?

Comment: `du -h
  0B ./branches
 40K ./hooks
4.0K ./info
2.0G ./logs/refs/heads
2.0G ./logs/refs
2.0G ./logs
  0B ./objects/info
4.5M ./objects/pack
4.5M ./objects
4.0K ./refs/heads
  0B ./refs/tags
4.0K ./refs
2.0G .`

Comment: master file is 2147483802 bytes